# Internal_error Exception when running a Jmeter test

Tags: jmeter

I am new to `jmeter`, but everytime I run my test I am getting this exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
>   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
>   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) 
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:533)

Can anyone suggest what might be the reason?

Comment: Please paste the code or recording from which you received the error

Answer (score 1):

Go to JMeter bin folder and open jmeter start script with some text editor:

Find this line:

> Environment variables:   JVM_ARGS - optional java args, e.g.
>   -Dprop=val

and add the following bellow:

> JVM_ARGS="-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"

Save file and run jmeter again.

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Hi Ivan I followed your solution but unable to find that line my jmeter file has only these lines :
#!/bin/sh

# Include the wrappers utility script
. /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh

find_java_runtime

find_jars /usr/share/jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar

run_java -Djmeter.home=/usr/share/jmeter org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver "$@"

Comment: Then add -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false after first argument you send (JMeter home).